# How do I uninstalling dart package?

Tags: dart

> WARNING: Files from a previous installation of Chocolatey were found at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey'.
> WARNING: An existing Chocolatey installation was detected. Installation will not continue.
> For security reasons, this script will not overwrite existing installations.

> Please use choco upgrade chocolatey to handle upgrades of Chocolatey itself.
> If the existing installation is not functional or a prior installation did not complete, follow these steps:
>
> - Backup the files at the path listed above so you can restore your previous installation if needed
> - Remove the existing installation manually
> - Rerun this installation script
> - Reinstall any packages previously installed, if needed (refer to the lib folder in the backup)

> Once installation is completed, the backup folder is no longer needed and can be deleted.

I tried to uninstall but I get an error

Comment: What error do you get for the uninstall? [edit] your question to include that.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150955/unable-to-install-dart-sdk?rq=2

Answer (score 0):

There had been an issue about not being able to uninstall the `dart-sdk` Chocolatey package if you are using Chocolatey 2.0 or higher: https://github.com/dart-lang/chocolatey-packages/issues/9

The issue is now fixed with Dart 3.1.1 so can you try again?